# Does Web Deploy work with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-deployment

I was wondering if Web Deploy found here: http://www.iis.net/expand/WebDeploy works with VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built into the GUI like Visual Studio 2010 is. You can still install it and run the scripts from command line or from the IIS 7 management screens.